# Conditional mapping among columns of two data frames with Pandas Data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I needed your advice regarding how to map columns between data-frames:

**I have put it in simple way so that it's easier for you to understand:**

df = dataframe

**EXAMPLE:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "X": [],
        "Y": [],
        "Z": []
    })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": ['', '', 'A1'],
        "C": ['', '', 'C1'],
        "D": ['D1', 'Other', 'D3'],
        "F": ['', '', ''],
        "G": ['G1', '', 'G3'],
        "H": ['H1', 'H2', 'H3']
    })
```

**Requirement:**

**1st step:**

We needed to track a value for X column on df1 from columns A, C, D respectively. It would stop searching once it finds any value and would select it.

**2nd step:**

If the selected value is **"Other"** then X column of df1 would map columns F, G, and H respectively until it finds any value.

Result:

```
    X
0   D1
1   H2
2   A1
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: In 1st step, you are trying to find the value for X column on df1. The dataframe is empty. What are you trying to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def first_non_empty(df, cols):
    """Return the first non-empty, non-null value among the specified columns per row"""
    return df[cols].replace('', pd.NA).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
    
col_x = first_non_empty(df2, ['A','C','D'])
col_x = col_x.mask(col_x == 'Other', first_non_empty(df2, ['F','G','H']))
df1['X'] = col_x
```

Comment: Hi 

Apologies for making the question ambiguous. I have edited it. Here the second step of your code is the first step.

That means, 

1st step:

we needed to track a value for X column on df1 from columns A, C, D respectively. It would stop searching once it finds any value. 

2nd step:
If the value is "Other" then X column of df1 would map columns F, G, and H respectively until it finds any value.

The result therefore, would be:

X
0   D1
1   H2
2   A1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please see my edited answer above

Comment: Could you please refer me to a source from where I could learn more?

Comment: There is no single resource to learn everything in pandas. I don't know everything either, only the parts to answer your question. Don't fret about learning resources, you will come to them naturally as you encounter and solve your problems